# When Reading from a Text File, how do I know if I've reached a new line?

Tags: c++, parsing

Given a text file that looks like this:

-10 15 -50 -60 70 -30

0 1

1 2

1 3

3 4

4 5

The first line of "-10 15 -50 -60 70 -30" is supposed to be put into an array.

The rest of the lines are supposed to be used as connecting points for an adjacency matrix.

How do I know if I've reached the end of the line?  This is my code so far.

```
string temp;
    while (getline(txtfile, temp, '\n')) {
        istringstream ss(temp);
        int num;
        while (ss >> num) {
            cout << num << endl;
        }
    }
```

I can separate all the numbers but I want to stop after I've reached the end of a line.

Editted Code:

```
ifstream txtfile("smallgraph.txt");
if (txtfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "Successfully opened file " << "graph.txt" << endl;
    int nodes = 0;
    int budget = 0;

    txtfile >> nodes >> budget;
    cout << nodes << " " << budget << endl;

    vector<int> firstLine;
    string temp;
    if (getline(txtfile, temp, '\n')) {
        istringstream ss(temp);
        int num;
        while (ss >> num)
            firstLine.push_back(num);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < firstLine.size(); i++) {
        cout << firstLine[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that code unsatisfactory? If you like you could use one pass rather than a loop, to capture the numbers to be put into an array, then `while(ss >> x >> y)` to gather the adjacency pairs.

Comment: Change `while (ss >> num) {
            cout << num << endl;
        }` to `while (ss >> num) {
            cout << num << ' ';
        } cout << endl;` Now you should be able to see where the end of line was.

Comment: There's no way of knowing using the `>>` operator. You must use `std::getline()`.

Comment: Asker used `getline` to grab a line. The end of the line will be the end of the `stringstream`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will read all the numbers in the file and print them each on a separate line.  If only needs small modifications to do what you want: just put the extracted numbers from the first line into a vector, then you can read pairs from the file and do whatever your adjacency matrix code needs with them.

```
std::vector<int> from_first_line;
string temp;
if (getline(txtfile, temp, '\n')) {
    istringstream ss(temp);
    int num;
    while (ss >> num)
        from_first_line.push_back(num);

    int first, second;
    while (txtfile >> first >> second) {
        // use for adjacency matrix...
    }
}
else
    std::cerr << "file contained no entries for vector\n";
```

Comment: I think I understand a little better but when I try to put it into practice it doesn't work out.  I've added my full edited code to my post.

Comment: The "edited code" in your question stops after populating the vector (without parsing the second and subsequent lines).  What's it not doing that you expect it to?

Comment: I just wanted to print the vector out to see if it was working but there's no output.  I have yet to implement the code to parse the remaining lines.

Comment: It works for me on my computer.  Note though that you don't output a final newline, so some terminal programs may return the cursor to the start of the line then print their prompt, removing the last unterminated line of output (the vector content).  Add a `std::cout << '\n';` at the end of the program to see if that's your problem.  If not that, add an `else` to your `is_open` test to report you couldn't open the file.  People often have trouble because their program's running in a different directory etc. - dozens of SO questions about that.